# How to sort fields names(not values) in alphabetic manner and create a new file based on it in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file which contains space separated field and its value. I want to sort this file based the the fields alphabetically.

```
v_party_id="49529957" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_src_system_id="VTX" v_pd_percent="0.0127" d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" 
v_party_id="49530058" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_src_system_id="VTX" v_pd_percent="0.00285" d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS"
```

After all the fields are sorted on field name (not value) alphabetically.
Expected output is-

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_id="49529957" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_src_system_id="VTX" v_pd_percent="0.0127" 
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_id="49530058" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_src_system_id="VTX" v_pd_percent="0.00285"
```

I am trying to do it via bash-

```
filecontent=( `cat "file1" `)
for t in "${filecontent[@]}"
do
        echo $t
done|sort
```

And this gives me output as -

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31"
v_accounting_standard="IFRS"
v_accounting_standard="IFRS"
v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT"
v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT"
v_party_id="49529957"
v_party_id="49530058"
v_pd_percent="0.00285"
v_pd_percent="0.0127"
v_src_system_id="VTX"
v_src_system_id="VTX"
```

How can I get the desired output which is only two rows with sorted fieldnames?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why in your expected output `v_` is before `d_` ?

Comment: As written previously: read a line. Split the line on spaces, into an array. Sort the array. Join the array with spaces. Output as a single line. You can do it in Bash, it will be faster in Awk, but it will be also faster in Python or Perl. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 on how to read a line. Check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: @MajidHajibaba : Yes, I corrected it

Comment: So correct `n_`  too!

Comment: Alphabetically `v_src_system_id` should appear after `v_pd_percent`

Comment: Can the values contain spaces? Is the requirement really to sort an unknow set of keys in every line or does the input have a fixed set of keys in a fixed order? If the input format is fixed, than you can simply print the input fields in a fixed order, e.g. `awk '{ print $5, $6, $1, $2, $3, $4 }' inputfile`. Please [edit] your question to clarify the requirements.

Comment: Shouldn't `v_party_id` come AFTER `v_party_default_status_cd` in your expected output instead of before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perl would be a good choice for sorting the fields:

```sh
perl -lane 'print "@{[sort @F]}"' file.txt
```

output:

```
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="49529957" v_pd_percent="0.0127" v_src_system_id="VTX"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="49530058" v_pd_percent="0.00285" v_src_system_id="VTX"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no spaces in values, you should be able to use the following:

```
# read a file line by line and split on spaces into an array
while IFS=' ' read -r -a elements; do
    # output array elements on separate lines, sort them and join with spaces
    printf "%s\n" "${elements[@]}" | sort | paste -sd' '
done < inputfile.txt
```

If there are spaces between `"... ..."` you have to write your own parser to tokenize the line.

Comment: Thanks much. Your code works fine. But I have about half million rows in my file. So I guess awk option is better for me.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` command. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"}
{
   split($0,a)
   j=0
   for (i in a){
      printf "%s", a[i] (++j<NF ? OFS : ORS)
   }
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You alread got a good GNU awk solution but if you don't have GNU awk then using any awk+sort in any shell on every Unix box with a decorate/sort/undecorate idiom:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NR, NF, $i}' file |
    sort -k1,1n -k3,3 |
    awk '{rec=rec sep $3; sep=OFS} ++cnt==$2{print rec; rec=sep=cnt=""}'
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="49529957" v_pd_percent="0.0127" v_src_system_id="VTX"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="49530058" v_pd_percent="0.00285" v_src_system_id="VTX"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      a[i] = $i
   j = 0
   for (i in a)
      printf "%s", a[i] (++j<NF ? OFS : ORS)
}' file

d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="49529957" v_pd_percent="0.0127" v_src_system_id="VTX"
d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_party_id="49530058" v_pd_percent="0.00285" v_src_system_id="VTX"
```

[**Working Online Demo**](https://ideone.com/socxMt)

**Details:**

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"` sorts an array with values in ascending strings order
- 1st for loop stores each field in array `a` with key as field position abd value as field value
- Due to presence of `PROCINFO` array will be sorted in alphabetic values order
- 2nd for loop prints each sorted entry

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. But your code gives a different result to me. after executing the awk command for the data given in the question, i get -

v_pd_percent="0.0127" d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_id="49529957" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_src_system_id="VTX"
v_pd_percent="0.00285" d_report_ref_date="2021-03-31" v_accounting_standard="IFRS" v_party_id="49530058" v_party_default_status_cd="NOTDFLT" v_src_system_id="VTX"

Comment: What's your awk version? This requires `gnu-awk`

Comment: awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: Check this [working demo](https://ideone.com/socxMt)

Comment: @Neha your gawk version 3.1.7 is 12 years and many revisions out of date. We're now on version 5.1.1 and you''re missing a ton of additional functionality (and bug fixes), including "sorted_in" which arrived in version 4.0. You should install a current version of gawk.